# Easiest way to automate a text report in R

Tags: r

I am using QGIS to batch query multiple spatial layers, which are then exported as individual csv files e.g. I have a shapefile of London, which then pulls out all the information from other layers such as schools, hospitals etc.

I am loading these csv files into R, and want to generate an automated report based on counts of hospitals, schools, sums of admissions etc.

Would the easiest way to generate a report be to 
1) generate tables of just the relevant columns and 
2) paste() statistics with strings of text e.g.

```
    > print(paste0("there are ", sum(Schools$Pupils)))
[1] "there are 2920"
> print(paste0("pupils attending ", nrow(Schools)))
[1] "pupils attending 5"
```

I wish to automate this as I plan to do much smaller geographies after looking at London

Comment: Have a look at `RMarkdown` reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clemsang pointed out in the comments you can use `rmarkdown` and the `knitr`-package in Rstudio.

After installing the package you can start an `rmarkdown` document with `file -> New File ->  R Markdown`.

You can create code cunks within ```{r chunk_name echo = FALSE} code ```, and have it executed within your document with or without showing the code, depending on `echo`.

With just ` code ` you can insert inline code, such as you are planning to do. To plot tables you can use the `kableExtra`-package.

You can save your rmarkdown-document, and render it inside you code with:

```
render(knit("C:/R/markdown/mydoc.Rmd", output = "C:/R/markdown/mydoc.html"))
```

This e.g creates a html-file in the specified directory.

Find out more here:
https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html

Comment: Brilliant. That is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to "accept" the answer, so others with the same question/problem know what worked for you :-)